# MemCache Type Initializer Exception

Tags: c#, .net, memcached

I have implemented MemCache in C#,its working fine with local system.
But when i published the code its trowing below exception :

The type initializer for 'Memcached.ClientLibrary.SockIOPool' threw an exception.   at Memcached.ClientLibrary.SockIOPool.GetInstance()

Please find the below code :

```
            SockIOPool pool;
            string[] servers = { "IP Address" };
            pool = SockIOPool.GetInstance();
            pool.SetServers(servers);

            pool.Failover = false;
            pool.Nagle = false;
            pool.Initialize();
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of exception and other details ?

Comment: is your GetInstance() method is static? or you need to create an instance of SockIOPool class? maybe check for null your SockIOPool.

Comment: Check the InnerException property of the TypeInitializationException; it is likely to contain information about the underlying problem, and exactly where it occurred.

Comment: This is the complete exception which captured in stack trace :                The type initializer for 'Memcached.ClientLibrary.SockIOPool' threw an exception. at Memcached.ClientLibrary.SockIOPool.GetInstance()

Comment: The GetInstance() method is static one

Answer (score 0):

Only the following static fields are constructed on the static method GetInstance():

```
 // logger
 private static ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SockIOPool));

 // store instances of pools
 private static Hashtable Pools = new Hashtable();
```

As you can see the Hashtable cannot be the problem, so it must be the Log. Please check that the log4Net version and platform are correct between your packages and MemCached references.

Comment: Hi Neill, log4Net versions are same and i didn't get what platform u r asking for, Is it .Net platform ?

Comment: 32bit or 64-bit...the only other thing, are you running multiple threads? because the static method is decorated with the attribute '[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]' which will lock the Type which may cause problems.